# what is the problem in build .apk file in flutter in this case?

Tags: flutter, apk, android-virtual-device

I have been writing an app in flutter recently Named app002 , But I faced with some problems I need to know how to solve them , I use a GitBash as a Terminal

> Flutter Doctor

```
 lamoh@DESKTOP-QUA3N6C MINGW64 /e/programes/Flutter_Req/sourceCode
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063], locale ar-DZ)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.40.2)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

this commande take too much time and not excuted

> flutter build apk

```
elamoh@DESKTOP-QUA3N6C MINGW64 /e/programes/Flutter_Req/sourceCode/app002
$ flutter build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Initializing gradle...                                              2,0s
Resolving dependencies...
```

i try this also but nothing

> $ flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64

```
    lamoh@DESKTOP-QUA3N6C MINGW64 /e/programes/Flutter_Req/sourceCode/app002
**$ flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64**
Initializing gradle...                                              2,3s
Resolving dependencies...
```

in the project directory a folder named build was created but in inside there are only  `app.dill` file exist . no apk no iOs files

help please !!! **thanks**

Comment: Looks like a duplicate. Please refer to this post - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59072744/flutter-build-apk-doesnt-work-and-shows-gradle-task-assemblerelease-failed-with/59073966#59073966](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59072744/flutter-build-apk-doesnt-work-and-shows-gradle-task-assemblerelease-failed-with/59073966#59073966)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `flutter build apk` instead of `appbundle`. An app bundle is intended to be sent to Google Play, which will generate and optimize the apk for you. Once done, the apk will be in the `build\app\outputs\bundle\release\` folder.

Answer (score 0):

finaly its take a long time but it's donne thanks

```
PS E:\programes\Flutter_Req\sourceCode\app003> flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
Running "flutter pub get" in app003...                              8,9s
Initializing gradle...                                              6,4s
Resolving dependencies...
  520,4s (!)
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                       314,3s (!)
Built build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app.aab (10.5MB).
```

where i can find the APK file !

Answer (score 0):

the size of your app is too big, to reduce there size run this

```
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
```

and then run this

```
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
```